# SQL subquery not producing correct results

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm using MySQL 5.7.15

**I'm trying to get a list of all the business that match the where clause (near a certain location), for each business I need to get the picture with the most likes. Here is where it gets complicated, if the business has a plan type other than 1 then I need the picture with the most likes where most_liked_picture.business_picture's value is 1, otherwise I just need the pictures with the most likes. In an attempt to do this I created an outer query that will give me all the businesses and an inner query with sub queries to give me the picture with the most likes that satisfies the order by clause.**

Two of the inner queries are not producing the desired results. It gives results for some of the rows but not all, which I find very strange. For now I have not tried to limit the results of the inner query to just one per outer query because I can't get the inner query sub's to produce the correct results.

When I break the sub queries out I get the correct results so I know the queries are good, it has to be the way I'm combining them?

I am self taught in SQL so if you see something that isn't standard or is weird please be gentle.

Here is the table structure and data:

```
businesses
+----+----------------------------+-----------+------------+----------------|
| id | name                       | lat       | lng        | point_location |
+----+----------------------------+-----------+------------+----------------|
|  1 | test_business_1            | 28.418908 | -81.586254 | POINT(lng,lat) |
|  2 | Sea_World                  | 32.764800 | 117.226600 | POINT(lng,lat) |
|  3 | Disneyland                 | 33.812100 | 117.919000 | POINT(lng,lat) |
|  4 | Disney World               | 28.417839 | -81.581235 | POINT(lng,lat) |
|  5 | business near Disney World | 28.408642 | -81.572607 | POINT(lng,lat) |
+----+----------------------------+-----------+------------+----------------|

business_plans
+----+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+------------+
| id | plan_type_id | business_id | user_id | start_date | end_date   |
+----+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+------------+
|  1 |            1 |           1 |       1 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31 |
|  2 |            2 |           1 |       2 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
|  3 |            2 |           2 |       2 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
|  4 |            1 |           3 |       1 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
|  5 |            2 |           4 |       1 | 2016-01-01 | 0000-00-00 |
+----+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+------------+

pictures 
+----+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | business_id | user_id | image_path                            | title                                 | lat       | lng        | point_location            | lifetime_likes | lifetime_dislikes | month_likes | month_dislikes | business_picture | business_main_picture | business_icon | effective_date      | expire_date         | updated_at          | created_at          |
+----+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           2 |       1 | sea world image_path_1                | sea world logo                        | 32.764800 | 117.226600 | POINT(lng,lat)             |              5 |                 5 |           5 |              5 |                1 |                     0 |             1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 |           3 |       0 | disney_image_path_2                   | disney main picture                   | 33.812100 | 117.919000 | POINT(lng,lat)             |              1 |                 0 |           1 |              0 |                1 |                     1 |             0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  3 |           3 |       2 | disney user uploaded pic              | NULL                                  | 33.812100 | 117.919000 | POINT(lng,lat)             |              5 |                 5 |           5 |              5 |                0 |                     0 |             0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  4 |           3 |       0 | disney expired pic                    | disney expired pic                    | 33.812100 | 117.919000 | POINT(lng,lat)             |             20 |                 0 |          20 |              0 |                1 |                     0 |             0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  5 |           3 |       2 | disney_highest_points                 | disney highest points                 | 33.812100 | 117.919000 | POINT(lng,lat)             |             10 |                 2 |          10 |              2 |                1 |                     0 |             0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  6 |           4 |       1 | disneyworld_highest_business_pic      | disneyworld_highest_business_pic      | 28.417839 | -81.581235 | POINT(lng,lat)             |             20 |                 1 |          20 |              1 |                1 |                     0 |             0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 | 2016-09-22 22:40:50 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  7 |           4 |       1 | disneyworld_highest_user_point_pic    | disneyworld_highest_user_point_pic    | 28.417839 | -81.581235 | POINT(lng,lat)             |             45 |                 1 |          45 |              1 |                0 |                     0 |             0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 | 2016-09-22 22:36:46 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  8 |           5 |       2 | near_disneyworld_highest_business_pic | near_disneyworld_highest_business_pic | 28.417839 | -81.581235 | POINT(lng,lat)             |             20 |                 1 |          20 |              1 |                1 |                     0 |             0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 | 2016-09-23 00:08:20 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+


users
+----+-----------+--------------------+
| id | username  | picture_path       |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
|  1 | test      | user1_picture_Path |
|  2 | username2 |                    |
|  3 | username3 |                    |
|  4 | username5 |                    |
|  5 | username5 |                    |
|  6 | username6 |                    |
|  7 | username7 | NULL               |
+----+-----------+--------------------+


user_picture_swipe
+----+------------+-------------+---------+-------+
| id | picture_id | business_id | user_id | liked |
+----+------------+-------------+---------+-------+
|  1 |          1 |           2 |       2 |     0 |
|  2 |          2 |           3 |       2 |     1 |
|  3 |          2 |           3 |       1 |     1 |
|  4 |          3 |           3 |       1 |     1 |
|  5 |          4 |           3 |       1 |     0 |
|  6 |          7 |           4 |       1 |     1 |
|  7 |          6 |           4 |       1 |     0 |
|  9 |          8 |           5 |       2 |     1 |
+----+------------+-------------+---------+-------+
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT businesses.id AS business_id, businesses.name AS business_name,     
  most_liked_picture.business_plan_type_id, most_liked_picture.picture_id, 
  businesses.lat, businesses.lng, most_liked_picture.image_path, 
  most_liked_picture.picture_title, most_liked_picture.lifetime_likes, 
  most_liked_picture.business_picture, 
  ST_Distance_Sphere(businesses.point_location, POINT(-81.581235, 28.417839)) AS  
  distance_from_user, 
  most_liked_picture.uploaded_username,   
  most_liked_picture.uploaded_user_image_path,   
  most_liked_picture.user_liked_picture 
FROM businesses LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT most_liked_picture.id AS picture_id, businesses.id AS business_id, 
        businesses.name AS business_name, 
        current_business_plan.plan_type_id AS business_plan_type_id, 
        businesses.lat, businesses.lng, most_liked_picture.image_path, 
        title AS picture_title, most_liked_picture.lifetime_likes, 
        business_picture, 
        ST_Distance_Sphere(businesses.point_location, POINT(-81.581235,                  
          28.417839)) AS distance_from_user, 
        CASE business_picture 
          WHEN 0 THEN user_uploaded_picture.username 
          ELSE "" 
        END AS uploaded_username, 
        CASE business_picture 
          WHEN 0 THEN user_uploaded_picture.picture_path 
          ELSE "" 
        END AS uploaded_user_image_path, 
        IFNULL(current_user_liked_picture, NULL) AS user_liked_picture
      FROM users AS user_uploaded_picture RIGHT JOIN (
        (SELECT business_id, plan_type_id 
         FROM business_plans 
         WHERE (CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) OR 
               ((end_date IS NULL) AND (CURRENT_DATE >= start_date))
         ) AS current_business_plan 
       RIGHT JOIN (businesses LEFT JOIN ( 
         (SELECT picture_id, liked AS current_user_liked_picture 
          FROM user_picture_swipes 
          WHERE (user_id = 1)
         ) AS user_picture_swipe 
       RIGHT JOIN pictures AS most_liked_picture 
         ON user_picture_swipe.picture_id = most_liked_picture.id) 
         ON businesses.id = most_liked_picture.business_id) 
         ON current_business_plan.business_id = businesses.id) 
         ON user_uploaded_picture.id = most_liked_picture.user_id 
      WHERE ST_Within(businesses.point_location, 
        envelope(linestring(POINT(-81.581235 - 5 / 
        abs(cos(radians(28.417839)) * 69),28.417839 - (5 / 69)), 
        POINT(-81.581235 + 5 / abs(cos(radians(28.417839)) * 69),28.417839 + 
        (5 / 69))))) 
      ORDER BY 
        IF(IFNULL(current_business_plan.plan_type_id, 1) != 1, 
          IFNULL(most_liked_picture.business_picture, 0), 0) DESC, 
        lifetime_likes DESC            
      ) AS most_liked_picture ON businesses.id = most_liked_picture.business_id 
WHERE ST_Within(businesses.point_location, envelope(linestring(POINT(-81.581235 
  - 5 / abs(cos(radians(28.417839)) * 69),28.417839 - (5 / 69)),POINT(-81.581235 
  + 5 / abs(cos(radians(28.417839)) * 69),28.417839 + (5 / 69))))) 
ORDER BY ST_Distance_Sphere(businesses.point_location, POINT(-81.581235, 
  28.417839));
```

Here are the results I'm getting (shortened to fit page):

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------+----------+---------------+
| business_id | name         | plan_type_id | likes | username | liked_picture |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------+----------+---------------+
|           4 | Disney World |         NULL |    20 |          |             0 |
|           4 | Disney World |         NULL |    45 | test     |             1 |
|           1 | test_business|            2 |       |     NULL |          NULL |
|           5 | business near|         NULL |    20 |          |          NULL |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------+----------+---------------+
```

The results I should be getting:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------+----------+---------------+
| business_id | name         | plan_type_id | likes | username | liked_picture |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------+----------+---------------+
|           4 | Disney World |            2 |    20 | test     |             0 |
|           4 | Disney World |            2 |    45 | test     |             1 |
|           1 | test_business|            2 |       |     NULL |          NULL |
|           5 | business near|         NULL |    20 | username2|             1 |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------+----------+---------------+
```

Sorry this post is so long. Any help is appreciated.

******************************* update for query *******************************

I finally figured it out! The outer query was the culprit, once it was removed I got the desired results. Here is the final query (using no right joins and no blocks in the from). Thanks to Used_By_Already for pointing me in the right direction.

```
SELECT businesses.id AS business_id, businesses.name AS business_name, 
  current_business_plan.plan_type_id AS business_plan_type_id, businesses.lat, businesses.lng, 
  most_liked_picture.id AS picture_id, most_liked_picture.image_path, title AS picture_title, 
  most_liked_picture.lifetime_likes, business_picture, picture_uploaded_user.username AS uploaded_username, 
  picture_uploaded_user.picture_path AS uploaded_user_image_path, 
  user_picture_swipe.current_user_liked_picture AS user_liked_picture,  
  ST_Distance_Sphere(businesses.point_location, POINT(-81.581235, 28.417839)) AS distance_from_user 

FROM 
    (SELECT business_id, plan_type_id 
     FROM business_plans 
     WHERE (CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) OR  ((end_date IS NULL) AND 
       (CURRENT_DATE >= start_date))) AS current_business_plan 
  INNER JOIN businesses ON current_business_plan.business_id = businesses.id  
  LEFT JOIN pictures AS most_liked_picture ON businesses.id = most_liked_picture.business_id 
  LEFT JOIN users AS picture_uploaded_user ON most_liked_picture.user_id = picture_uploaded_user.id 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT picture_id, liked AS current_user_liked_picture 
     FROM user_picture_swipes 
     WHERE (user_id = 1)) AS user_picture_swipe ON most_liked_picture.id = user_picture_swipe.picture_id 

WHERE ((expire_date IS NULL) OR (CURRENT_DATE() <= expire_date)) AND 
  ST_Within(businesses.point_location, envelope(linestring(POINT(-81.581235 - 5 / abs(cos(radians(28.417839)) * 69),28.417839 - (5 / 69)), POINT(-81.581235 + 5 / abs(cos(radians(28.417839)) * 69),28.417839 + (5 / 69))))) 

ORDER BY 
  IF(IFNULL(current_business_plan.plan_type_id, 1) != 1, IFNULL(most_liked_picture.business_picture, 0), 0) DESC, 
  most_liked_picture.lifetime_likes DESC, 
  ST_Distance_Sphere(businesses.point_location, POINT(-81.581235, 28.417839))
```

Now if I could just figure out how to only return 1 picture for each business. I tried using an aggregate MAX(most_liked_picture.lifetime_likes) and GROUP BY businesses.id however it removes my order by so I don't get the correct picture.

Comment: you didn't explain how did you get that result

Comment: I suggest you ignore that right join is permitted syntax. Deny yourself the ability to use it. This will cause you to - more carefully - consider the sequence of joins and what to use as the initial table (from .....).  Also your sample data doesn't satisfy the final where clause: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46d035/1

Comment: Newbee what do you mean explain how I got the result? I ran the query in mysqlworkbench, is that what you mean.

Comment: Used_By_Already I could use inner joins however it omits all results for plan_type_id and username. For the sample data I omitted the expire_date from the pictures table due to space, sorry I should have clarified

Comment: You "swap" control of a query from left to right and also seem to use a nested right/left join. My brain hurts just reading it. Start by choosing the correct "from" starting point and after that only use LEFT JOINS. I'm not insisting you use only inner joins. just stop using right joins. It will help eventually.

Comment: Yeah sorry I know my brain hurts too lol, do you want me to repost the modified query with left joins?

Comment: My suggestion is to start really small. Looks like you want to have "from businesses" then left joins, do it bit by bit. I cannot achieve the desired result because the final where condition cannot be met. Check your data matches your expectations.

Comment: Oh and point_location is not null, I just can't represent a spatial point as text (or at least I don't know how). In the insert statement you can use POINT(lng,lat) to fill that column with the correct data

Comment: Another piece of advice, do NOT delay using the ON conditions as a block. include them as you enter each join. This way the joining logic is much easier to follow and the behaviour of the joins will be more predictable.  (i.e. keep it simple). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This simple query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/546807/sql-subquery-not-producing-correct-results):

```
SELECT
      b.*
    , bp.business_id
    , bp.plan_type_id
    , p.likes
    , p.b_pic
    , u.username
    , u.picture_path
FROM business_plans AS bp
INNER JOIN businesses AS b ON bp.business_id = b.id
left join pictures AS p on b.id = p.id
left join users AS u on p.user_id = u.id
WHERE (CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN bp.start_date AND bp.end_date)
     OR 
      (bp.end_date IS NULL AND CURRENT_DATE() >= bp.start_date)
```

produces a result like this:

```
id name            lat lng point_location business_id plan_type_id likes b_pic username  picture_path       
-- --------------- --- --- -------------- ----------- ------------ ----- ----- --------- ------------------ 
1  test_business_1 28  -82 null           1           1            5     1     test      user1_picture_Path 
1  test_business_1 28  -82 null           1           2            5     1     test      user1_picture_Path 
2  Sea_World       33  117 null           2           2            1     1     null      null               
3  Disneyland      34  118 null           3           1            5     0     username2 null               
4  Disney World    28  -82 null           4           2            20    1     null      null               

(5 row(s) returned)

(25 row(s) affected)
```

I suggest you restart from scratch.

*Perhaps* this is the starting point? But truly I am not sure

```
SELECT b.*, bp.*
FROM business_plans AS bp
INNER JOIN businesses AS b on bp.business_id = b.id

-- sample data needs start_date or end_date

WHERE (CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) 
OR (end_date IS NULL AND CURRENT_DATE >= start_date)
```

Also make sure your test data will satisfy the where clauses

```
CREATE TABLE businesses
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(26), `lat` numeric, `lng` numeric, `point_location` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO businesses
    (`id`, `name`, `lat`, `lng`, `point_location`)
VALUES
    (1, 'test_business_1', 28.418908, -81.586254, NULL),
    (2, 'Sea_World', 32.764800, 117.226600, NULL),
    (3, 'Disneyland', 33.812100, 117.919000, NULL),
    (4, 'Disney World', 28.417839, -81.581235, NULL),
    (5, 'business near Disney World', 28.408642, -81.572607, NULL)
;


CREATE TABLE business_plans
    (`id` int, `plan_type_id` int, `business_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO business_plans
    (`id`, `plan_type_id`, `business_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (3, 2, 2),
    (4, 1, 3),
    (5, 2, 4)
;


CREATE TABLE pictures
    (`id` int, `business_id` int, `user_id` int, `lat` int, `lng` int, `point` int, `likes` int, `b_pic` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO pictures
    (`id`, `business_id`, `user_id`, `lat`, `lng`, `point`, `likes`, `b_pic`)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 1, 32.764800, 117.226600, NULL, 5, 1),
    (2, 3, 0, 33.812100, 117.919000, NULL, 1, 1),
    (3, 3, 2, 33.812100, 117.919000, NULL, 5, 0),
    (4, 3, 0, 33.812100, 117.919000, NULL, 20, 1),
    (5, 3, 2, 33.812100, 117.919000, NULL, 10, 1),
    (6, 4, 1, 28.417839, -81.581235, NULL, 20, 1),
    (7, 4, 1, 28.417839, -81.581235, NULL, 45, 0),
    (8, 5, 2, 28.417839, -81.581235, NULL, 20, 1)
;


CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `username` varchar(9), `picture_path` varchar(18))
;
    
INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `username`, `picture_path`)
VALUES
    (1, 'test', 'user1_picture_Path'),
    (2, 'username2', NULL),
    (3, 'username3', NULL),
    (4, 'username5', NULL),
    (5, 'username5', NULL),
    (6, 'username6', NULL),
    (7, 'username7', NULL)
;


CREATE TABLE user_picture_swipe
    (`id` int, `picture_id` int, `business_id` int, `user_id` int, `liked` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO user_picture_swipe
    (`id`, `picture_id`, `business_id`, `user_id`, `liked`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 2, 0),
    (2, 2, 3, 2, 1),
    (3, 2, 3, 1, 1),
    (4, 3, 3, 1, 1),
    (5, 4, 3, 1, 0),
    (6, 7, 4, 1, 1),
    (7, 6, 4, 1, 0),
    (9, 8, 5, 2, 1)
;
```

Comment: INSERT INTO businesses
    (`id`, `name`, `lat`, `lng`, `point_location`)
VALUES
    (1, 'test_business_1', 28.418908, -81.586254, POINT(lng,lat)),
    (2, 'Sea_World', 32.764800, 117.226600, POINT(lng,lat)),
    (3, 'Disneyland', 33.812100, 117.919000, POINT(lng,lat)),
    (4, 'Disney World', 28.417839, -81.581235, POINT(lng,lat)),
    (5, 'business near Disney World', 28.408642, -81.572607, POINT(lng,lat))                                                                                        That will populate your point_location column. If you use NULL it won't work.

Comment: sqlfiddle just went down and I don't have MySQL available, sorry.

Comment: which table is supposed to have columns: start_date and end_date? ALWAYS prefix a column by the table or table alias in our queries.

Comment: Sorry start_date and end_date are in business_plans, I just omitted the columns because it made the results hard to read when I posted them in the window. I suppose I should post all the data but I think it's going to be really hard to read

Comment: Please look here for a simulation use sql server as sqlfiddle is down: sql-subquery-not-producing-correct-results

Comment: you do need to post all table/columns that are used by the query. however I have gone as far as I can I think. Please take another look above (I changed it) I think the basic structure of your query should be fro business_plans inner join businesses then left join pictures and users. You can add extra conditions to the left joins if needed

Comment: While this wasn't the exact answer it pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!